# Does Filesystem caching system of Django stores the cache on server or the user system?

Tags: django, caching, django-caching

I read the documentation as well but could not get clearing on this.
Also, do we need to install anything extra for this to work?
 I have added below code in settings.py file :

```
    CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': '/var/tmp/django_cache',
        'TIMEOUT': 518400,  # 6 days - 6*24*60*60
        'OPTIONS': {
            'MAX_ENTRIES': 1000
        }
    }
}

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += [
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: The cached pages are on the server in the directory specified -- `/var/tmp/django_cache`. As a rule, web pages in browsers (more specifically the JavaScript(s)) do *not* have permission to write to the local filesystem. This is A Good Thing. Otherwise you would have a security hole big enough you could drive a 747 through it.

Comment: @PeterRowell : but why I cannot see any files building into the directory and if web browsers don't have permission then will caching work?

Comment: Without further information, my guesses are: the directory does not exist, you lack necessary permissions to create / write files there, and/or you are not using per-view caching or the `{% cache %}` tag in your templates. Did you [Read *all* of The Friendly Manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching)?

Comment: @PeterRowell, sir i have  created /var/tmp/django_cache in the root of the project, and also gave the 777 permissions.
not using any tag inmy template, using per-site caching.